# How to switch users in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to switch users in Cygwin using Cygwin's `login` command. It throws an error saying:

```
/bin/bash: No such file or directory. Operation not permitted.
```

I am new to Cygwin. How I can switch between users?

Comment: su {username} {password}

Comment: that does not work either, it gives the same error. I have added user in Windows, how do I add that user in cygwin?

Comment: Try ssh:   ssh username@localhost

Comment: $ ssh gundu@localhost gives the following error
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: when I type /etc/passwd I get the following, do you see any problem?/etc/passwd: line 9: gundu:unused:1008:513:gundu,U-BSA25G-SWLABgundu,S-1-5-21-606747145-1078145449-725345543-1008:/home/gundu:/bin/bash: No such file or directory

Comment: This is most likely a firewall issue.

Comment: what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Does [this link](http://www.solomonson.com/content/new-user-cygwin) help?

Comment: Check your firewall. Add an exception for port 22. This should work after :  ssh gundu@localhost

Comment: When I click on Windows Firewall in Control Panel it says "Windows Firewall settings cannot be displayed because the associated service is not running. Do you want to start the Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing(ICS) service?"

Comment: @DavidDuncan I did refer this link, but no luck.

Comment: @Kisaragi: You have to be running the sshd service for `ssh` to a Cygwin box to work; it doesn't run by default. There are [instructions here](http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/) for Cygwin under Windows 7. You *shouldn't* need to go through `ssh` just to switch users, though. (I've been using Cygwin for a long time, but I've never bothered setting up more than just my own user account.)

Comment: You haven't said *how* you're trying to switch users, other than "with Login User Password format".  Are you using the `login` command? I've just tried that myself, and I get `login: no shell: /bin/bash: Operation not permitted`, which isn't what you reported. I am able to login using `ssh`, but only because I've set up the `sshd` service. I don't know why `login` doesn't work. You might try asking on the [cygwin mailing list](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/).

Comment: @KeithThompson: You are correct when I use the login command, i get the login: no shell: /bin/bash: Operation not permitted message. How do I login using ssh? How to check if sshd service is running or not?

Comment: I tried $ ssh gundu@bsa25g-SWLAB
ssh: connect to host bsa25g-SWLAB port 22: Connection refused is the message I get.

Comment: @user2495173: If you installed Cygwin on the system, and you don't know whether you're running the sshd service, you probably aren't. See the [instructions](http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/) I posted previously. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: This is what I get: stambi@bsa25g-SWLAB /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/gundu
$ cygrunsrv -Q sshd
Service             : sshd
Display name        : CYGWIN sshd
Current State       : Stopped
Command             : /usr/sbin/sshd -D


stambi@bsa25g-SWLAB /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/gundu
$ /usr/sbin/sshd -D
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.

Comment: I did ssh-host-config, now I am able to switch from stambi to gundu but when I swicth from gundu to stambi, it does not allow. It says Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why login doesn't work. But I have an easy workaround for this, running cygwin as the desired user, you can use RUNAS or automatize something using PSEXEC.

RUNAS:

```
runas /user:HOSTNAME\<user> D:\cygwin-64\Cygwin.bat
```

PSEXEC:

```
psexec \\HOSTNAME -u DOMAIN\<user> -p <password> D:\cygwin-64\Cygwin.bat
```

You even can pass commands/run scripts silently to Cygwin like this:

```
psexec -accepteula \\HOSTNAME -u DOMAIN\<user> -p <password> D:/cygwin-64/bin/run.exe /usr/bin/bash -lic \"/home/username/file.sh\"
```

Although the question is quite old maybe someone else is looking for this. I've documented this and other options [here](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/windows/different-cygwin-usages/1317).